# The strange loss fluctuation when loading previous trained model

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, loss

I am using PyTorch for deep learning now.

I trained a model before and had the parameters saved. Loss values before the end of the training were about `0.003~0.006`.

However, when I load the same model with the same training data, loss values at first fluctuate to around `0.5`.

The loss values then decrease very quickly to around `0.01` in ~10 iterations and now decreasing slowly.

Does anyone know why this situation keep happens? Since I am loading the same model/ training data. I was expecting the loss values would start at a similar level as the end of last training.

Comment: What did you save exactly while saving the model? Did you save `state_dict` of optimizer as well or not?

Answer (score 3):

When resuming a training, you should not only load the network's weights but also the optimizer state. For that, you can use `torch.save`:

```
torch.save({
            'epoch': epoch,
            'model_state_dict': model.state_dict(),
            'optimizer_state_dict': optimizer.state_dict(),
            'loss': loss,
            ...
            }, PATH)
```

Then, for resuming the training:

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.train()
optimizer = TheOptimizerClass(*args, **kwargs)

checkpoint = torch.load(PATH)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state_dict'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer_state_dict'])
epoch = checkpoint['epoch']
loss = checkpoint['loss']
```

If you don't save the optimizer state, you loss important information such as the current learning rate, momentum etc. This is probably the cause of your problem.

Reference:
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-loading-a-general-checkpoint-for-inference-and-or-resuming-training

Comment: Thank you. Seems I didn't save the previous hyperparameters properly. The problem is solved now.